# Woocommerce flat buttons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to make the buttons like ADD TO CART in Woocommerce plugin flat?

example: http://www.thamon.co.uk/product/sal-leaf-coin-pouch/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply some custom CSS here.
Here is the CSS i used the last time i needed to do this:

```
.woocommerce a.button.alt, 
.woocommerce button.button.alt, 
.woocommerce input.button.alt, 
.woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt, 
.woocommerce #content input.button.alt, 
.woocommerce-page a.button.alt, 
.woocommerce-page button.button.alt, 
.woocommerce-page input.button.alt, 
.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit.alt, 
.woocommerce-page #content input.button.alt { background: #00a0d2; text-shadow: none; color: #fff; border: 0; padding: 8px 7px 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.woocommerce a.button.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce button.button.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce input.button.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce #content input.button.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce-page a.button.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce-page button.button.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce-page input.button.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit.alt:hover, 
.woocommerce-page #content input.button.alt:hover { background: #11b1e3; text-shadow: none; color: #fff; }

.woocommerce a.button, 
.woocommerce button.button, 
.woocommerce input.button, 
.woocommerce #respond input#submit, 
.woocommerce #content input.button, 
.woocommerce-page a.button, 
.woocommerce-page button.button, 
.woocommerce-page input.button, 
.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit, 
.woocommerce-page #content input.button { background: #dfdbdf; text-shadow: none; color: #333; border: 0;  padding: 8px 7px 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.woocommerce a.button:hover, 
.woocommerce button.button:hover, 
.woocommerce input.button:hover, 
.woocommerce #respond input#submit:hover, 
.woocommerce #content input.button:hover, 
.woocommerce-page a.button:hover, 
.woocommerce-page button.button:hover, 
.woocommerce-page input.button:hover, 
.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit:hover, 
.woocommerce-page #content input.button:hover { background: #e5e5e5; }
```

Please, note that you will have to change your `background` and `color` to the values that would fit your design. The `background` property is necessary in order to overwrite the gradient that WooCommerce applies to the buttons.

Comment: This is because your style.css is being enqueued before the woocommerce main stylesheet. To fix this, either enqueue your style.css later, or add an additional prefix to all styles, for example `.woocommerce a.button.alt` would become `.woocommerce .main-container a.button.alt` or `.woocommerce #container a.button.alt`